# How can I create an even spaced separated outline with border radius?

Tags: css

I've been trying some solutions  found around the web, but they all are just a bit . . . off.

We have a design for a button's :focus style, like so:

[image: button style][image: button::focus style]

That's 2px of empty space and a 2px outline.

Here's what we are doing now:

```css
&::after {
      border-radius: 18px;
      content: "";
      display: block;
      margin: -2px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

    &:focus::after {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px blue;
    }
```

which is *almost* good. See how it is just off-keel?

[image]

Is there a more reliable approach to this sort of design problem? Nudging the position properties by .5 pixels can hack it into shape but it just breaks elsewhere and makes my CSS bone ache.

Comment: I will note, at certain browser zoom settings, it falls in line, looking most off-keel at % zooms over 100% that are odd numbered. Ideally I can make a best result for any user, but I accept it might be a hard constraint.

Comment: Clarification on previous comment that might change the nature of the question . . . It looks even at 100%, 150%, and 200% browser zoom settings, but off-center when viewing at 110%, 125%, and 175%. What are the rendering mechanics at work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with border and background-clip:

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .2s;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 3px solid transparent; /* we start transparent */
  padding: 3px; /* control the space */
  background: green content-box; /* color only the content */
}

button:hover {
  border-color: blue; /* change color on hover */
}

body {
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<button>Accept</button>
```

Comment: Excellent. This is the kind of solution that's been under my nose all along! Thanks much!